# Handling Session in Angular/MVC Architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, session

I am having angular 6/asp.net mvc application.My front-end code is in angular and using web api for backend DB interaction.Once I build angular code,I put dist folder in MVC application and refer published js from MVC layout.cshtml and then host complete application in IIS with windows authentication(in intranet).

my requirement is if session is idle for 10mins,then show session expire dialog message or redirect it to some angular view. I am not sure how to implement a session timeout in this architecture. I googled it but didn't find any relevant links. Do I need to change authentication?

If someone can redirect it to some relevant links,it would be really helpful

Comment: Have you use forms authentication in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a token that have an expiration, then add a guard in your angular that would check this token.

If expired then redirect to a new angular page informing the user of the expired session.

In my project I have use MVC as a container of my angular page *(my workplace have an existing SSO using MVC forms authentication)* and Angular 6 for the front end.

1. MVC to generates token after user authentication.
2. Create a route guard to check token validity.
   export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

   ```
   constructor(private _authService: AuthService, 
           private _router: Router) {}

   canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
       // check if token has expired
       if (this._authService.isAuthenticated()) {
           return true;
       } else {
           // redirect to some info page 
           this._router.navigate(['/error']);
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Angular to check token expiration in auth-guard.

   ```
   export class AuthService {
       tokenObject: AuthUser = new AuthUser();
       authClaims: AuthUserClaim[] = [];

       constructor() { 
           let jwt = localStorage.getItem('test-token');
           this._assignToken(jwt);
       }   
       isAuthenticated(): boolean {        
           let jwt = localStorage.getItem('test-token');
           if (HELPER.isTokenExpired(jwt)) {
               return false;
           } else {
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
   ```